# A foliation version of S.Husseini counter example in fixed point theory

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, foliations, fixed-point-theorems

In this question we are indirectly inspired  by [an example by  S.Husseini  Amer. J.Math 1977](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/The-Products-of-Manifolds-with-the-f.p.p.-Need-Not-Husseini/b712d6f1a9548a90c40558b9ea108ec04a623dcb)

"The Products of Manifolds with the f.p.p. Need Not have the f.p.p"

who gave an example of two  fixed point manifolds $M,N$ such that $M\times N$ is not a fixed point space. One can consider the fixed point property as a kind of a problem in discrete dynamical system. So in this question we would like to consider a continuous dynamical version of this result by S.Husseini.  May be a flow version of the concept of fixed points is the concept of  closed orbits, compact leaves of the 1-dimensional foliation associated to the (non vanishing) vector field which generate our given flow.

The above is a motivation to ask the following question:

> What is an example of two compact manifolds $M,N$ whose product $M\times N$ admits a foliation without compact leaf but every foliation of $M$, and every foliation of $N$ has at least one compact leaf.

Note: In this question we do not specify the dimension of the foliations under consideration but we require that the foliation has non trivial dimension.  Neither 0 dimensional nor the full dimensional foliation.

So in this question the obvious answer $S^1 \times S^1$, as the ambient space of  the kronecker foliation, is excluded.  Since $S^1$ foliates itself by a single leaf, a trivial foliation.